# Search and replace within entity result set

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given 3 database tables:

```
A (id, type, code, ...)
B (code, text)
C (id, key, val)

A.code == B.code
A.id == C.id (C.id is not a unique key, multiple entries are possible)
```

B.text ***might*** contain replacement variables, in the form `$KEY$`. (So, for example, it might contain: "This is a $SOMEKEY$". C ***might*** contain the key and a replacement value:

```
$SOMEKEY$: Message
$SOMEOTHERKEY$: Text
```

Currently I perform the replacement in two steps. First, I get all the required data:

```
var result = from a in context.A where a.type == myType
             join b in context.B on a.code == b.code
             select new {
                 ID = a.id,
                 Code = a.code,
                 Text = b.Text
             };
```

Next, I get all matching replacement variables. It might be that there is no key available in C.

```
var data = context.C.Where(c => result.Select(r => r.ID).Contains(c));
```

Then I loop over the lists and perform the replacement:

```
foreach (var r in result) {
    var local = r;
    foreach (var c in data.Where(c => c.id == local.ID)) {
        local.Text = local.Text.Replace(c.key, c.val);
    }
}
```

Now, aside from any database compatibility issues and readability aside, would it be possible to perform the search and replace within the first database query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's really problematic is that you need to apply multiple replacements over the same variable and I can't see a way to do that in Linq.

But, what you might be able to do is reduce it from two queries and a foreach loop down to one query and a foreach loop:

```
// group by the replacement string and gather all the replacements
var result = from a in context.A
    join b in context.B on a.code equals b.code
    join c in context.C on a.id equals c.id
    group new {b.text, c.key, c.val} by b.code into grp
    select grp;


// loop through each group and apply replacements
foreach(var r in result) {
    var text = r.First().text;

    foreach(var c in r) {
        text = text.Replace(c.key, c.val);
    }
}
```

It's not clear exactly which of your fields are primary keys and what exactly is unique, but I believe that you should be able to find away to do a single query that will at least have all the data you need to work with and you can avoid doing a second query. You may have to adjust what you are grouping and what you are grouping by.

Comment: After some further tests and discussions with colleagues we settled for the same idea. We've also found that, even if it were possible with LINQ, our DB2 connector would not be able to coop with it. (If it's a DB2 limitation or the connector I cannot tell, my knowledge of it is limited.) Therefore I'm marking this as answered. Thanks. :-)